# How to create DataGridsViews on tabs that are being auto generated

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

When loading my excel file with many sheets, I'm taking the name of each sheet and having tabs in a tabControl automatically generate.  This works. Next I'm having trouble making it so a new and different dataGridView gets generated on each tab.  Here is my code so far for this part

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows) {
  comboBox1.Items.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
  tabControl2.TabPages.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

  DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
  TabPages.Controls.Add(grid);  // red line under TabPages  **********
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set aside the new TabPage so you can add controls to it:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows) {
    string name = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    var tabPage = new TabPage(name);
    var grid = new DataGridView();

    tabPage.Controls.Add(grid);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(name);        
    tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tapPage);
}
```

Comment: Oh I left out the line that creates the grid. You accepted so I'm guessing you figured it out but I'll edit to fix this.

Comment: I got it to work add ing DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
 above the tab page.  Thanks for your help.    If you happen to have a quick fix to setting the dimensions of the new data grid views that'd be helpful too.

Comment: I would need to know the requirements to help out. Generally with SO, it's best to create a new question for each question. Chances are if you search SO, you'll find a question already asked that shows you how to size a control. Most likely doing something like new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill }; will be what you want. Or you can add a FlowLayoutPanel to the TabPage and then add the DataGridView to the FlowLayoutPanel.